# What is causing this NotImplementedError in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I need to write a  code which trains a network given one single batch of training data and computes the loss on the complete validation set for each epoch as well. Set `batch_size = 64`.
Also, need to provide the graph the training and validation loss over epochs.

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self): 
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        
        self.net_layer = Sequential(
            nn.Flatten(),   
            nn.Linear(64*64,30),
            nn.Sigmoid())
        
    def foward(self, x): 
        x = self.net_layer(x)
        return x
    
model = Net()

nepochs = 2
losses = np.zeros(nepochs)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(nepochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

    # initialise variables for mean loss calculation
    running_loss = 0.0
    n = 0
    
    for data in train_loader:
        inputs, labels = data
        
        # Zero the parameter gradients to remove accumulated gradient from a previous iteration.
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward, backward, and update parameters
        outputs = model(inputs) # running network
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels) # calculating loss function
        loss.backward() # backpropogating network
        optimizer.step() # update model parameters with gradient decsent
    
        # accumulate loss and increment minibatches
        running_loss += loss.item()`enter code here`
        n += 1
       
    # record the mean loss for this epoch and show progress
    losses[epoch] = running_loss / n
    print(f"epoch: {epoch+1} loss: {losses[epoch] : .3f}")
```

I got this far and getting the following error:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zir31.png)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the complete error message [as text rather than an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) to make this question more accessible to search engines and readers with impaired vision.

Comment: You have a typo in `def foward`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.